# Expansion of medical Latin abbreviation (ventric. later. dextr.)

Tags: grammar-choice, abbreviations

I don't know enough Latin grammar to properly expand this abbreviation: *ventric. later. dextr.*

I am aware that it means the right lateral ventricle in the brain, the lateral ventricles as a whole being called *ventriculi lateri*, but that's obviously plural.

So, what is the correct full phrasing for specifically the right-side one? *Ventriculus laterus dextrus?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close! *Lateralis* ("lateral") is a third-declension adjective, so it takes the ending *-is* instead of *-us* for this form. Similarly, *dextr.* is actually *dexter*, not *dextrus*: it's one of the odd adjectives that end in R in the masculine nominative singular.

So all together, this would be the *ventriculus lateralis dexter*: the right lateral ventricle.

(The plural should likewise be *ventriculi later**ales***, not *lateri*, in Classical Latin; Google suggests this is true in medical terminology as well.)